# Appium+ WebdriverIO finding element issues

Tags: android, appium, webdriver-io

I created a small test android app which has a text box and a button and am able to build this and launch on a real device (android) using WebDriverIO.

However, when I try to select elements I can't locate them.

Example: the text field has the following properties:
**id**: editTextTextPersonName

**input type**: textPersonName

**contentDescription**: @string/fldName1 (which is the string "helpme" in the xml)

Using UIAutomatorViewer I can see the field has the following:

**resouce**-id** = com.example.myfirstapp:id/editTextTextPersonName

**package** = android.widget.EditText

**class** = android.widget.EditText

**content-desc**: helpme

However, I cannot locate this using WebDriverIO.

I have tried
`$('~helpme').setValue('test')`
but that doesn't work.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, you're doing everything correct. AFAIK there is an issue with the `$('~helpme')` selector within WebdriverIO/Appium not being able to find the correct element / failing on Android.

What I did in the past, especially if I needed to use cross-platform locators, was that I created a method like this

```
const locatorStrategy = (selector: string): string => {
  return driver.isIOS ? `id=${selector}` : `//*[@content-desc="${selector}"]`;
};
```

which could be used like this

```
$(locatorStrategy('input-email'));
```

You can also validate your selector with Appium Inspector. This is how Appium Inspector looks like

[image]

You can then press this button

[image]

then select XPATH and add this `//*[@content-desc="input-email"]` selector

[image]

hit Search which will lead to this

[image]

So in your case, if you would use or something like above or just this

```
$('//*[@content-desc="helpme"]').setValue('test')
```

then it should work

Comment: The above is for Xpath. How would you pass an Accessibility ID?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean?